# Show that (p ⇒ q) ⇒ (r ⇒ s) ⇐⇒ (p ⇒ r) ⇒ (q ⇒ s) is a tautology?(without truth table)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Show that  $(p ⇒ q) ⇒ (r ⇒ s) ⇐⇒ (p ⇒ r) ⇒ (q ⇒ s)$   is a tautology?

I am having a little trouble in proving this proofs without truth tables

the idea for solve this question is to work out left side and right side separately, trying to match the result.but i can't match the result :(

I have tried:

left side:

`1.` $(p ⇒ q) ⇒ (r ⇒ s)$

`2.` $(¬p ∨ q) ⇒ (¬r ∨ s)$

`3.` $¬(¬p ∨ q) ∨ (¬r ∨ s)$

`4.` $(p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬r ∨ s)$

`5.` $[(p ∧ ¬q) ∨ ¬r] ∨ s$

`6.` $[(p ∨ ¬r) ∧ (¬q ∨ ¬r)] ∨ s$

---

right side:

`1.` $(p ⇒ r) ⇒ (q ⇒ s)$

`2.` $(¬p ∨ r) ⇒ (¬q ∨ s)$

`3.` $¬(¬p ∨ r) ∨ (¬q ∨ s)$

`4.` $(p ∧ ¬r) ∨ (¬q ∨ s)$

`5.` $[(p ∧ ¬r) ∨ ¬q] ∨ s$

`6.` $[(p ∨ ¬q) ∧ (¬r ∨ ¬q)] ∨ s$

however don't see where this will help me. I don't really know how to go on from her.

any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not a tautology; for example, pqrs FFTF and FTFF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $p, r, s$ are F, and $q$ is T.

Then $(p \to q) \to (r \to s)$ is T

And $(p \to r) \to (q \to s)$ is F

So on that valuation, $((p \to q) \to (r \to s)) \leftrightarrow ((p \to r) \to (q \to s))$ is F, and *isn't* a tautology.

[That's assuming, as your answer attempt assumes too, that $\to$ takes precedence over $\leftrightarrow$, so we should bracket as shown.]

Comment: @m.r Notice that the DNF equivalences for the statements do practically tell you to consider what happens when $p$ and $s$ are false, as those make the evaluations of the statements hinge on the centremost disjuncts, $\neg r$ and $\neg q$ respectively. $~$ So if $p$ and $s$ are false, then opposing evaluations for $q$ and $r$ will suffice to give the statements opposing evaluations.$$(p\to q)\to(r\to s) \iff (p\wedge\neg q)\vee\neg r\vee s \\ (p\to r)\to (q\to s)\iff (p\wedge\neg r)\vee\neg q \vee s$$